# Conditional formatting between versions

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have a range in excel that is formatted conditionally using VBA to colour the cells based on the value. It is quite a simple setup that runs at the opening of the WB, clearing and resetting once opened.

It worked about a month ago, and still does on some computers/versions, but somehow it does not execute on a new computer running excel 2013.

The error excel generates is:

> Invalid procedure call or argument

The code generating the error is:

> MyRng.Formatconditions.Add.Type:=xlexpression, formula:= *My conditional format formulae*

I've been searching for an answer, but could not find anything WRT differences in formatting between versions.

Comment: That should be formula1:= not formula - is that a typo or did formula work in earlier versions?

Comment: Yes, it has worked in previous versions. I have a typo above, the code does have formula1:= written therein.

Comment: I wonder. In the VB Editor, just check in Tools,references that it isn't showing something as "missing". A bad reference can make stuff behave weirdly.